# Need help on my first Test Apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have written an Apex class which works well in dev environment, but I am having a tough time writing a test class that will give me more then 59% coverage. I tried using snippets from this and other sites, but it only got me so far. I know I can add some garbage code to the class and put commands on the same line to raise the percentage coverage, but I really would like to understand how write a good coded test class. Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is my class and test class.

```java
global class updateCOATotalCashAndGiftCount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
    global Map<Id, AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c> coaMap;
    global Map<Id, AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c> cMap;

    //global String query2 = 'select AQB__ChartofAccounts__c, AQB__Amount__c from AQB__Transaction__c where AQB__ChartofAccounts__c != NULL and AQC_Cash_Transaction__c = TRUE and AQB__Type__c In(\'Payment\',\'Grant Payment\') and AQB__ChartofAccounts__c=\'a0r1U000005VVr9QAG\'';
    global String query = 'select AQB__ChartofAccounts__c, AQB__Amount__c from AQB__Transaction__c where AQB__ChartofAccounts__c != NULL and AQC_Cash_Transaction__c = TRUE and AQB__Type__c In(\'Payment\',\'Grant Payment\') and AQB__ChartofAccounts__r.LastModifiedDate != TODAY';

    global updateCOATotalCashAndGiftCount() {
        coaMap = new Map<Id, AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c> ();
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
       return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
        
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<AQB__Transaction__c> scope) {
        List<AQB__Transaction__c> trs = (List<AQB__Transaction__c>)scope;
   
        // fill map for AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c object, adding totals as we traverse through batches
        for (AQB__Transaction__c t : trs) {
            if (coaMap.containskey(t.AQB__ChartofAccounts__c)) {
                AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c a = coaMap.get(t.AQB__ChartofAccounts__c);
                a.AQC_Total_Cash__c += t.AQB__Amount__c;
                a.AQC_Total_Cash_Gift_Count__c++;
                coaMap.put(t.AQB__ChartofAccounts__c, a);
            }
            else{
                coaMap.put(t.AQB__ChartofAccounts__c, new AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c (Id = t.AQB__ChartofAccounts__c, AQC_Total_Cash__c = t.AQB__Amount__c, AQC_Total_Cash_Gift_Count__c = 1));
            } 
        }
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){ 
        cMap = new Map<Id, AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c> ();
        Integer numGovernorLimit = 9999;
        Integer numBreak = 0;
        try {
            // copy a subset of Map for update, take care of governor limits
            for(Id key :coaMap.keySet()){
                cMap.put(key, new AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c (Id = key, AQC_Total_Cash__c=coaMap.get(key).AQC_Total_Cash__c, AQC_Total_Cash_Gift_Count__c=coaMap.get(key).AQC_Total_Cash_Gift_Count__c));
               if(numGovernorLimit <= numBreak) {
                   update cMap.values(); 
                   cMap.clear();
                   break;
                }
                numGovernorLimit--;
            }
            if(cMap.size() > 0) {
                system.debug(loggingLevel.debug, 'cMap update remainder: '+cMap.size());
                update cMap.values();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex) {system.debug(Ex);}
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```java
@isTest
public class updateCOATotalCashAndGiftCountTest {
 static testMethod void testQueryLocator() {
        Database.QueryLocator QL;
        Database.BatchableContext BC;
        Map<Id, AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c> coaMap;
        Map<Id, AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c> cMap;
        
        List<AQB__Transaction__c> TAList = new List<AQB__Transaction__c>();
        updateCOATotalCashAndGiftCount AU = new updateCOATotalCashAndGiftCount();
        QL = AU.start(bc);
       
        coaMap = new Map<Id, AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c> ();
        cMap = new Map<Id, AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c> ();
     
        Database.QueryLocatorIterator QIT =  QL.iterator();
        while (QIT.hasNext())
        {
            
            AQB__Transaction__c TA = (AQB__Transaction__c)QIT.next();           
            TA.AQB__Amount__c = 1;

            AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c a = coaMap.get(TA.AQB__ChartofAccounts__c);
            a.AQC_Total_Cash__c += TA.AQB__Amount__c;
            a.AQC_Total_Cash_Gift_Count__c++;
            coaMap.put(TA.AQB__ChartofAccounts__c, a);

            System.debug(TA);
            TAList.add(TA);
            update cMap.values();
        }       
       
        AU.execute(BC, TAList);
        AU.finish(BC);       
    }
}
```

Coverage:

[image: image of coverage]

Comment: Thanks for posting your question. In terms of writing good test classes, one of the key things for me is that you should be testing the process not just the individual methods that make up the class you're testing. Rather than calling the individual methods like you're doing, think about how you'd call this from the context in which it is being used.

Comment: Thanks Callum, the problem is that I don't understand why some lines are red and what to add to my test class to make that red go away. It seems that whatever test statements I add, it does not change that 59% pass coverage. If someone can tell me what lines of code I need to add to test class, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Can you tell me when `coaMap.containskey(t.AQB__ChartofAccounts__c)` line will run becuase it's value is empty initially and when you add a value for any id it will not come back again in list so this will never be called. so you can not cover this if condition at all

Comment: Thanks Gopal, I see what you are saying. I added the following lines before the loop, but it didn't change the coverage. I am trying to understand what other requirements I am missing.                          
     coaMap = new Map<Id, AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c> ();
        coaMap.put('a0r1U000005VRRvQAO', new AQB__LLChartofAccounts__c (Id = 'a0r1U000005VRRvQAO', AQC_Total_Cash__c = 64712.0, AQC_Total_Cash_Gift_Count__c = 1));
      update coaMap.values();